# Air to Air localconnection

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to connect two Air Application using LocalConnection. It works when I open as SWF and EXE(published) but when I publish it to Air files they doesn't work. I am creating one interactive screen that send command to another Air Application(Projector). This few lines on code will only appear of "frame one".

Sending:

```
var sending_lc:LocalConnection;
sending_lc = new LocalConnection();
```

Receiving:

```
var receiving_lc:LocalConnection;
receiving_lc = new LocalConnection();
receiving_lc.connect("my_lc_as3");
receiving_lc.client = this;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this doc http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

To make LocalConnection work between AIR apps, allowDomain() needs to be called.
For example, in your case:

```
// For receiving_lc
// Here receiving_lc is an Air app with app Id = com.sample
receiving_lc.allowDomain('app#com.example');
receiving_lc.connect("my_lc_as3");

// For sending_lc
sending_lc.send('app#com.sample:my_conn', 'my_method');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.

I don't have a server for this so what do i allow in this segment (app#com.example)?

Comment: It is supposed to be a local path.

Comment: @CKLai `com.example` here is just the id of your AIR app. Try to take the time to read [**From an AIR application to another AIR application**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) ...

Comment: Thanks KevinVFX and akmozo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you KevinVFX and akmozo.

It's working now and this is the code.

Sending:

```
var sending_lc:LocalConnection;
sending_lc = new LocalConnection();
sending_lc.send("app#APPIDReceiving:my_lc_as3", "my_method");
```

Receiving:

```
var receiving_lc:LocalConnection;
receiving_lc = new LocalConnection();
receiving_lc.allowDomain("app#APPIDSending");
receiving_lc.connect("my_lc_as3");
receiving_lc.client = this;

function my_method():void{
trace("linked");
}
```